# How to kill a background worker including its metadata in Postgres?

Tags: c, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I've created a background worker. I want to manually delete it and relaunch a new one. At this point, I am doing the following:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
select pg_terminate_backend(pid);
```

It certainly stops the current worker. But I think it does not delete the metadata about the bgworker. In the config file, the default number of bgworkers that can execute simultaneously is set to 8 and I am only able to repeat the above process for first eight times. After this point, I am not able to register the bgworker again. I suspect the metadata is not being deleted.

Is there any other way to kill the bgworker completely?

Comment: Please refer the below URL for more information:

    https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CALF3U-4To6FfrBcMWH2uR7yubcm03L9G0pJYMcyv0fNA6A%3DZ3Q%40mail.gmail.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please refer the below URL for an answer:

```
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CALF3U-4To6FfrBcMWH2uR7yubcm03L9G0pJYMcyv0fNA6A%3DZ3Q%40mail.gmail.com
```